# Can I combine a @Query definition with a Specification in a Spring Data JPA repository method?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to use both `@Query` annotation and specification in one repository method? For example I'd like to have a method like this:

```
@Query(value="SELECT e from EMPLOYEE where firstName <> ?1")
public Page<Employee> findEmployeeBySomethigFancy(String firstName, Pageable pageable, Specification<Employee> emp);
```

Is it possible or should I build the whole query as a `Predicate` and remove the `@Query` annotation?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

First thing, you should read this [Spring blog post](http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/).

Second, according to the [`JpaSpecificationExecutor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html) interface, that your repositories should implement, the following method take a `Specification` argument:

- `count(Specification<T> spec)`
- `List<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec)`
- `Page<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable)`
- `List<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec, Sort sort)`
- `T findOne(Specification<T> spec)`

So, you can't mix a `@Query` definition with a `Specification`.

However, since you can express the `firstName <> ?1` condition using a `Specification` and because you combine as many specifications as you want, you can rewrite the whole `@Query` using `Specification`(s) only.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I know that I can combine as many specification as I want, but I have couple of methods with *@Query* annotation and now there is a need to use Specification, so I have to rewrite existing queries to Specification's objects. I thought that maybe there is a way to somehow combine *@Query* and Specification.

Comment: For the API implementer point of view, it's much easier to separate those concerns and to offer specific querying facilities. Combining them might complicate the implementation even further.

Comment: This subject is amazing, I have to do a many-to-many join on a JPA query method, and I pass a Specification and Pageable item. For sure the @Query can't be mixed with it (I tested it). And this brings no answers to my cup. don't know how to manage to get my query corresponding with a relationship table, and keeping my Specification and Pageable items :(

Comment: @Alex Did you find any solution for your concern? Because am having a similar situation, I can't combine both Query and Specification.  Please help us if you have any solution.

Comment: @AnshulKabra it was a very long time ago, but I can remember ended up using QueryBuilder and CriteriaAPI to extends my JpaRepository and implement the query by hand. Receiving Pageable and Specification, I create the whole query and Page item.

Comment: I have a similar issue. The data is selected by a complex query using several cta to add aggregated values. I think this can't be rewritten using specification. The only way I found is a database view. However, this comes with other problems (like dynamic conditions cant be added to the cta part of the query). How to handle such cases?

Answer (score 1):

I did this workaround in order to have a response other than the entity type using the specification I have, maybe it can help you to resolve your needs without @Query:

```
public ImovelFilterResponseDTO getImovelsFilterByCriteria(Specification<Imovel> specification) {
    ImovelFilterResponseDTO imovelFilterResponseDTO = new ImovelFilterResponseDTO();
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<BigDecimal> query = builder.createQuery(BigDecimal.class);
    Root<Imovel> root = query.from(Imovel.class);
    Predicate predicate = specification.toPredicate(root, query, builder);
    if (predicate != null) {
        query.where(predicate);
    }
    BigDecimal areaHectaresMax =  entityManager.createQuery(query.select(builder.max(root.<BigDecimal>get("areaHectares")))).getSingleResult();
    imovelFilterResponseDTO.setFilterMaxArea(areaHectaresMax);
    return imovelFilterResponseDTO;
}
```