# How to use specification for a custom JPQL query

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-jpa

Is there any way to add Specification for a custom `JPQL` query like below :
I am able to create custom jpql, but not sure how to add additional specification conditions to it. I need to add  specification dynamically.

EmployeeRepository.java

@Query(value = "select new . EmployeePojo(c.employee_id, d.deplt_id) from Employee c left join c.dept d where c.id =1")

```
Page<EmployeePojo> getData(Pageable request);
```

I should add specification to above custom jpql

Comment: Looks like this question has been answered in this post<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379522/can-i-combine-a-query-definition-and-specifications-on-one-spring-data-jpa-repo?noredirect=1&lq=1>.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I combine a @Query definition and Specifications on one Spring Data JPA repository method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379522/can-i-combine-a-query-definition-and-specifications-on-one-spring-data-jpa-repo)