# How can I pass a specification to a custom query on repository interface of spring data?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, specifications

In repository interface which extends JpaRepository, if we have our custom query e.g "getAllCustomersWhoAreOlderThan", how can we pass custom specification to this method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I combine a @Query definition and Specifications on one Spring Data JPA repository method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379522/can-i-combine-a-query-definition-and-specifications-on-one-spring-data-jpa-repo)

Comment: I didn't get any resolution from this thread. So I asked the question

Answer (score 0):

you can't pass Specifications in mix @Query (or query-methods).
the following queries using Specifications:

- count(Specification spec)
- List findAll(Specification spec)
- Page findAll(Specification spec, Pageable pageable)
- List findAll(Specification spec, Sort sort)
- T findOne(Specification spec)

Comment: These are the methods provided in repository. Can we use specifications in custom queries just like we use pageable or sort?

Comment: yes of course, we can use Pageable and Sort in custom queries

Comment: That's just an example. Can we use SPECIFICATIONS, LIKE we use paging and sorting

Comment: you can use specification just in general queries (ex: findAll() )