# Get lists of ids with JPA instead all Object

Tags: spring, jpa

I am trying to get only the list of ids from a JPA repository.
Instead of using

```
List<Case> findAll(Specification<Case> filter);
```

Something like

```
List<Integer> findAll(Specification<Case> filter);
```

because I don´t need the full object. There is a lot of data on each record, and a lot of records.

Answer (score 0):

The two easiest options that come to my mind right now:

1. Fetch the results as you normally do, but build your return result(List) after the the database fetch in a separate step
2. Fetch your list of integers via a native query.

Answer (score 0):

Do it by JPQL query:

```
@Query(value = "select c.id from Case c WHERE case.name like ?1")
List<Long> findIDsByName(String name);
```

Comment: It is possible to use Specifiactions with annotated queries?

Comment: No. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379522/can-i-combine-a-query-definition-and-specifications-on-one-spring-data-jpa-repo

Comment: But you can add conditions on above query without using Specification

Comment: Just in case, if you need more than one column,  you may implement a DTO projection. (Hibernate. https://thorben-janssen.com/dto-projections/ )

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used select clauses from JPA: https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select

adding where conditions:
https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/where