# Spring Data @Query + Specification

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, specifications

Can you help me connect Specifications and Query, Pageable works perfectly but I have a problem with Specifications, no search parameters are added to where.

```java
public interface RakebackRepository extends JpaRepository<Rakeback, Long>,JpaSpecificationExecutor<Rakeback> {

    @Override    
    @Query(value = "SELECT new domain.model.poker.rakeback.Rakeback(ppr.playerId, SUM(ppr.rakeSum), SUM(ppr.fullRakeBackSum), max(ppra.rakeBackBalance), max(ppra.rakebackRank)) FROM Rakeback as ppr LEFT JOIN ppr.Rakeback as ppra on ppra.status = 'active' LEFT JOIN ppra.rakebackRank as rbb on ppra.rakeBackRankId = rbb.id GROUP BY ppr.playerId ")   
    Page<Rakeback> findAll(Specification<Rakeback> specification, Pageable pageable);
    
    }
```

Here is SQL from logs

```
select pokerplaye0_.player_id as col_0_0_,  sum(pokerplaye0_.rake_sum) as col_1_0_,  sum(pokerplaye0_.full_rake_back_sum) as col_2_0_,  max(pokerplaye1_.rake_back_balance) as col_3_0_,  max(pokerplaye1_.rake_back_rank_id) as col_4_0_ 
from rakeback.players_rakebacks pokerplaye0_  
left outer join rakeback.players_rakebacks pokerplaye1_ on pokerplaye0_.player_id=pokerplaye1_.player_id and (pokerplaye1_.status='active')  
left outer join rakeback.rakeback_settings pokerrakeb2_ on pokerplaye1_.rake_back_rank_id=pokerrakeb2_.id and (pokerplaye1_.rake_back_rank_id=pokerrakeb2_.id) 
group by pokerplaye0_.player_id 
order by pokerplaye0_.player_id desc limit ?
```

Here is my Speec

```
public class RakebackListSpec {

private final OperatorService operatorService;
private final PlayerService playerService;



public static Specification<Rakeback> byPlayerId(Long id) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) ->
            criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("playerId"), id);
}

public static Specification<Rakeback> byOperator(Integer operatorId) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) ->
            criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("operatorId"), operatorId);
}

public Specification<Rakeback> getSpec(RakebackListRequestDto request) {

    Specification<Rakeback> spec = Specification.where(byOperator(operatorService.getOperator().getId()));

    if(request.getOpPlayerId() != null){
        CorePlayer player = playerService.getPlayerByOpPlayerId(request.getOpPlayerId());
        spec = spec.and(byPlayerId(player.getId()));
    }


    return spec;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`@Query` and `Specification` cannot be combined. See [this SO Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379522/can-i-combine-a-query-definition-with-a-specification-in-a-spring-data-jpa-repo) for details.

Comment: Maybe there are some alternative options for generating dynamic where in the query?

Comment: Yes, `Specification`. Have you read up on it in the Spring Data documentation?